# GCP Project creation date

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How can I discover the creation date for a GCP project I have access to?

I have been given Owner permissions to it but I can't find this information anywhere in the Google Cloud Platform, I searched in the project [settings page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings?project=project-id-123) and anywhere I could think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out it can be discovered through the Google Cloud SDK, which is available both by using [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell) or by [downloading it](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) locally.

The command to use is:

```
gcloud projects describe project-id
```

The output is this:

```
createTime: '2020-05-27T13:57:09.746Z'
lifecycleState: ACTIVE
name: project-name
parent:
  id: '123456789012'
  type: organization
projectId: project-id
projectNumber: '123456789013'
```